# How to read and update a datetimeoffset field using classic asp?

Tags: datetime, asp-classic, sql-server-2014, datetimeoffset

I have a field in sql server 2014 db with datatype DateTimeOffset, how to create a proper Datetimeoffset using classic asp to update this field?
For example I have a 2 variables first one has the datetime and the second one has the offset and I want to combine both to put in the Datetimeoffset db field.

And also how to read from Datetimeoffset db field as datetime in classic asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary data access mechanism for Classic ASP is ADO.  This is used from ASP, VBScript, and VB6.

To get support for the `datetimeoffset` type, and other newer features of SQL Server, you need to use the SQL Native Client as the underlying data provider for ADO.  Simply set both `Provider=SQLNCLI11` and `DataTypeCompatibility=80` in your connection string, [as described in the MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978(v=sql.120).aspx).

Then you can simply interact with your `datetimeoffset` field like you would any other.  Since [all VBScript variables are Variant typed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf.aspx), and there's no variant subtype for `DateTimeOffset`, the field value will be mapped to a `Variant` with a `String` subtype.  The string representation is similar to `2015-12-27 19:51:35.4005420 -08:00`, where the number of decimals corresponds to the precision of the field in your database.